# Trying to maximize an expression with integer and real variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve [this equation](https://imgur.com/x0B7cNn)

The link has a screen capture of the equation and the solution. I am looking for the values of a1 and a2 in particular, but they need to be real numbers. s1 and s2 are integers. Now if I remove the condition of integers, then (as expected) the computation takes too long (it hadn't finished for an hour). My questions are:

1. Is it possible to define a1 and a2 to be reals, and s1 and s2 to be integers?
2. I would like to reduce the possible values of a1 and a2 to the tenth decimal point (i.e. between 0 and 1, it can have 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...0.9). Can this be done in *Mathematica*?

Edit (The code for the equation):

```
Maximize[{3/100000 - (
   Subscript[s, 1]*Subscript[a, 1] + 
    Subscript[s, 2]*Subscript[a, 2])/(50000 Subscript[a, 1]) - (
   3 (Subscript[s, 1]*Subscript[a, 1] + 
      Subscript[s, 2]*Subscript[a, 2]))/(25000 Subscript[a, 2]) + 1/(
   400000000000 Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[a, 2]) + (
   3 (Subscript[s, 1]*Subscript[a, 1] + 
      Subscript[s, 2]*Subscript[a, 2])^2)/(
   100000 Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[a, 2]) + (9 Subscript[a, 1])/(
   100000 Subscript[a, 2]), 
  Subscript[a, 1] >= 1 && Subscript[a, 1] <= 5 && 
   Subscript[a, 2] >= 1 && Subscript[a, 2] <= 5 && 
   Subscript[s, 1] + Subscript[s, 2] == 10 && Subscript[s, 1] >= 0 && 
   Subscript[s, 2] >= 0}, {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], 
  Subscript[s, 1], Subscript[s, 2]}, Integers]
```

Comment: Please provide the equation as code and not an image, so that we can copy-paste it instead of typing it out. As for point 2., you could simply define `b1 = 10*a1`, `b2 = 10*a2` and restrict `b1, b2` to integers between 0 and 10.

Comment: The inequalities for a1 and a2 automatically define them as real in Mathematica.  Check [`Element`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) for defining symbols as `Integers`, etc.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, Thank you for point 2! I will try that method today. I have edited the question and copied the code for the equation.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, a1 and a2 are defined as reals only if I remove the Integers specification from the equation. Otherwise, they come out to be integers always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact optimization with mixed real and integer variables is not yet implemented.

```
ClearAll[a, s]

Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n];
Format[s[n_]] := Subscript[s, n];

Maximize[{3/100000 + 1/(400000000000*a[1]*
            a[2]) + (9*a[1])/
         (100000*a[2]) - 
       (a[1]*s[1] + a[2]*s[2])/
         (50000*a[1]) - 
       (3*(a[1]*s[1] + a[2]*s[2]))/
         (25000*a[2]) + 
       (3*(a[1]*s[1] + a[2]*s[2])^2)/
         (100000*a[1]*a[2]), 
     a[1] >= 1 && a[1] <= 5 && 
       a[2] >= 1 && a[2] <= 5 && 
       s[1] + s[2] == 10 && 
       s[1] >= 0 && s[2] >= 0, 
     Element[s[1] | s[2], Integers]}, 
   {a[1], a[2], s[1], s[2]}]

(*  Maximize::mixdom: Exact optimization with mixed real and integer variables is not yet implemented. >>

Maximize[{3/100000 + 1/(400000000000 Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[a, 2]) + (
   9 Subscript[a, 1])/(100000 Subscript[a, 2]) - (
   Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[s, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[s, 2])/(
   50000 Subscript[a, 1]) - (
   3 (Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[s, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[s, 2]))/(
   25000 Subscript[a, 2]) + (
   3 (Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[s, 1] + Subscript[a, 2] Subscript[s, 2])^2)/(
   100000 Subscript[a, 1] Subscript[a, 2]), 
  Subscript[a, 1] >= 1 && Subscript[a, 1] <= 5 && Subscript[a, 2] >= 1 && 
   Subscript[a, 2] <= 5 && Subscript[s, 1] + Subscript[s, 2] == 10 && 
   Subscript[s, 1] >= 0 && 
   Subscript[s, 2] >= 0, (Subscript[s, 1] | Subscript[s, 2]) ∈ 
   Integers}, {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[s, 1], Subscript[s,
   2]}]  *)
```

So you must use [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html)

```
NMaximize[{3/100000 + 1/(400000000000*a[1]*
            a[2]) + (9*a[1])/
         (100000*a[2]) - 
       (a[1]*s[1] + a[2]*s[2])/
         (50000*a[1]) - 
       (3*(a[1]*s[1] + a[2]*s[2]))/
         (25000*a[2]) + 
       (3*(a[1]*s[1] + a[2]*s[2])^2)/
         (100000*a[1]*a[2]), 
     a[1] >= 1 && a[1] <= 5 && 
       a[2] >= 1 && a[2] <= 5 && 
       s[1] + s[2] == 10 && 
       s[1] >= 0 && s[2] >= 0, 
     Element[s[1] | s[2], Integers]}, 
   {a[1], a[2], s[1], s[2]}]

(*  {0.00928, {Subscript[a, 1] -> 5, Subscript[a, 2] -> 1., Subscript[s, 1] -> 10,
   Subscript[s, 2] -> 0}}  *)
```